# SQLite - Deleting a row that is referenced as a foreign key

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

While trying to delete a row that is referenced as a foreign key (for experimental purposes), I get a runtime exception. I understand that I am trying to violate the foreign key constraint, I am just confused about the logcat message because it refers to a completely different part of my code.

This is my `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;

    final String SQL_CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            CategoriesTable.TABLE_NAME + "( " +
            CategoriesTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            CategoriesTable.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
            ")";

    final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            QuestionsTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY + " INTEGER, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY + ") REFERENCES " +
            CategoriesTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + QuestionsTable._ID + ")" + 
            ")";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
    fillCategoriesTable();
    fillQuestionsTable();
}
```

Here I am filling the table with the initial questions, and then I try to delete a row from the categories table, **to violate the foreign key constraint on purpose (to test it):**

```
private void fillQuestionsTable() {
    Question q1 = new Question("Easy: A is correct",
            "A", "B", "C", 1, Question.DIFFICULTY_EASY, 1);
    addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2 = new Question("Medium: B is correct",
            "A", "B", "C", 2, Question.DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM, 2);
    addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3 = new Question("Medium: C is correct",
            "A", "B", "C", 3, Question.DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM, 3);
    addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4 = new Question("Hard: A is correct",
            "A", "B", "C", 1, Question.DIFFICULTY_HARD, 4);
    addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5 = new Question("Hard: B is correct",
            "A", "B", "C", 2, Question.DIFFICULTY_HARD, 5);
    addQuestion(q5);
    Question q6 = new Question("Hard: C is correct",
            "A", "B", "C", 3, Question.DIFFICULTY_HARD, 6);
    addQuestion(q6);

    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + CategoriesTable.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = 1");
}
```

I get a runtime exception. **Please notice that I try to violate the foreign key constraint on purpose and just want to understand the exception.**

My first question is:

1) The crash is because of the deletion, but why does logcat only talk about adding the questions to category 4,5 and 6 (which are not in my categories table in the first place)?

> Error inserting difficulty=Hard option1=A question=Hard: C is correct category_id=6 answer_nr=3 option3=C option2=B
>                                                                                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)

Why does it not talk about deleting a referenced column as I would expect?

2) Why does it throw a runtime exception, whereas trying to add a question that has a category which does not exist in the categories table, just ignores the SQLite command, but doesn't crash the app?
Is a runtime exception the expected behavior when violating a foreign key constraint by trying to delete a referenced column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) The crash is because of the deletion, but why does logcat only talk
>   about adding the questions to category 4,5 and 6 (which are not in my
>   categories table in the first place)?

No. The Crash, or at least the message shown, is because of what it says: a FOREIGN KEY constraint violation, which happens before the deletion (in `addQuestion(q6);`) and thus the deletion never happens.

Explaining the FOREIGN KEY constraint and why it failed is a little difficult because it appears that you have mixed up table columns. However, my guess is that that itself is not an issue.

More specifically you define a FOREIGN KEY constraint using

```
FOREIGN KEY(column_in_this_table_which_you_have_right)
    REFERENCES the_other_table_which_you_have_right
        (column_in_the_other_table_????)
```

For the column in the other table you have  `QuestionsTable._ID` it should be `CategoriesTable._ID`. However, they are probably called the same. So this doesn't cause an issue.

The error message includes **category_id=6**

Assuming they both resolve to ID then you are effectively saying

Only allow the insertion of a row in the **questions** table if the **category_id* column of the **questions** table matches (can reference) a row in the **categories** table where the **ID** column is the same as the **category_id** (i.e. 6).

**In short, the displayed messages says there is no category with an id of 6.**

---

> Why does it not talk about deleting a referenced column as I would
>   expect?

Because it crashed before getting to `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + CategoriesTable.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = 1");`

---

> 2) Why does it throw a runtime exception, whereas trying to add a
>   question that has a category which does not exist in the categories
>   table, just ignores the SQLite command, but doesn't crash the app?

Because in all likelihood your App will crash in numerous places without. You are saying this is something pretty important to the design. I have little doubt that if the ignore option were the case you'd be far more contrary to that (i.e. best option available nobody is forcing you to define the constraint). Although if that's what you want you may wish to check out [4.2 Deferred Foreign Key Constraints](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

---

> Is a runtime exception the expected behavior when violating a foreign
>   key constraint by trying to delete a referenced column?

To reiterate you didn't get that far.

However, you may wish to check out[4.3 ON DELETE and ON UPDATE Actions](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

### Edit - The Confusion Explained.

In short, the crash is actually due to the DELETE constraint. The INSERT constraints are trapped but displayed as the standard `insert` method is being utilized. The log, if you look at it carefully, will show this, as is explained below.

Here's an example based upon your code that I put together:-

```
04-11 21:47:10.241 1927-1927/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting option1=A category_id=6 option2=B option3=C difficulty=Hard answer_nr=3 question=Hard: C is correct
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.addQuestion(DatabaseHelper.java:70)
        at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.fillQuestionsTable(DatabaseHelper.java:97)
        at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:52)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:17)
        at askit.questionaire.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 21:47:10.245 1927-1927/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-11 21:47:10.245 1927-1927/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6294288)
04-11 21:47:10.245 1927-1927/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{askit.questionaire/askit.questionaire.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1665)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
        at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.fillQuestionsTable(DatabaseHelper.java:99)
        at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:52)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:17)
        at askit.questionaire.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

You are seeing the equivalent of:-

```
04-11 21:47:10.241 1927-1927/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting option1=A category_id=6 option2=B option3=C difficulty=Hard answer_nr=3 question=Hard: C is correct
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
```

However, this doesn't result in the App crashing.

- If you run the App, after deleting the database, with the DELETE commented out and look at the log you will see the same in the log, even though the App doesn't crash.

What you need to do is continue through the log and you will find the equivalent of:-

```
04-11 21:47:10.245 1927-1927/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-11 21:47:10.245 1927-1927/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6294288)
04-11 21:47:10.245 1927-1927/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{askit.questionaire/askit.questionaire.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
```

This is the crash i.e. the **`FATAL EXCEPTION:`**

If you continue, you will see **caused by**, this is where you look so you have:-

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1665)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
    at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.fillQuestionsTable(DatabaseHelper.java:99)
    at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:52)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
    at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:17)
    at askit.questionaire.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
```

If you look through the log **caused by** you will see that the first line that mentions your package is:-

```
at askit.questionaire.DatabaseHelper.fillQuestionsTable(DatabaseHelper.java:99)
```

Line 99 (your line number would be different as would be the package) points to

[image]

- Note I changed the line to use the CONSTANT (`CategoriesTable._ID`) for the category ID column.

Comment: But the thing is, if I skip the delete part, my app does NOT crash while trying to add a question with a category that does not exist. It just does not add the question (and keeps the app running). This is what confuses me. I don't have this runtime exception if I don't try to delete the category.

Comment: Then what you are probably doing is not looking at the whole log/right stack-trace. My guess is that you have the inserts wrapped in try/catch so you trap them so processing continues and further down you get the actual crash stack-trace.

Comment: That would explain why if you remove the delete it all appears to be good.

Comment: Makes sense, but I don't have any try/catch blocks

Comment: The other potential factor is that `onCreate` is run within a transaction.  Would have to see more of your code to be able to run it.

Comment: Well I can paste the SQLiteOpenHelper but it has 200 lines

Comment: I'd also need the Question class. However, it's getting late here so wouldn't be able to look into it until tomorrow anyway.

Comment: @FlorianWalther solved, well at least the cause. The answer has been edited.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I will read it in more detail as soon as possible.

Comment: So trying to add a question that has a non existing category will just be ignored, but does not cause a crash, right? Whereas trying to delete a category that is referenced in 1 or more questions without "delete cascade" results in a crash. Are your observations the same?

Comment: @FlorianWalther as you have it setup then yes.  `insert` defaults to `insert or ignore` (`insertOrThrow` method wouldn't) and covers other constraints e.g. NOT NULL, UNIQUE (no real problem as far as referential integrity). However deleting will be a problem as it would mess up referential integrity. So yes same/similar observations.

Comment: Great! I can't possibly thank you enough for all your effort!

Comment: I just realized why the app crashed.. Because I wrote "WHERE ID =" instead of "WHERE _ID ="